# Calling JS function from ASP.NET codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two javascript functions in my aspx page. They use some fabric.js functions.

```
function saveCanvas() {
    js = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
    $get('<%= txtJSON.ClientID%>').value = js;

}
function loadCanvas() {
    js = $get('<%= txtJSON.ClientID%>').value;
    canvas.clear();
    canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(js);
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

And in the codebehind:

```
 Protected Sub SaveJSON()
    Dim scriptKey As String = "123"
    Dim javaScript As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>saveCanvas();</script>"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), scriptKey, javaScript)
 End Sub

Protected Sub LoadJSON()
    Dim scriptKey As String = "456"
    Dim javaScript As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>loadCanvas();</script>"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), scriptKey, javaScript)
End Sub
```

Now my question: Why does loadCanvas work while saveCanvas does not? txtJSON is not populated with the JSON-string.
Calling the saveCanvas function from the aspx page works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `saveCanvas` after the postback is done and at that point the canvas data is long gone.

If you have a button "Save" then you need to call `saveCanvas` when it is clicked so that the data is saved before the browser posts the page back to the server:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save" OnClickClick="saveCanvas()" />
```

Comment: I indeed have a Save button. If I add your "onclick" event I get an error: translated "javascript is not a member of the aspx page.": Foutbericht van compiler: BC30456: javascript is geen lid van ASP.plattegrond_aspx.

Comment: Please understand that I also have a "saveCanvasbutton_click" event in my codebehind. At first I called the "saveCanvas" from here, but that didn't work.

Comment: This worked:<asp:Button id="btnSave" runat="server" onClientClick="saveCanvas()" OnClick="btnSave_Click"  Text="Opslaan"/>   Thanks!